# Not sure if I should add detail to question or submit answer and start new question

Tags: discussion

I have found a solution to the problem in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793121/redirect-to-file-mysteriously-does-nothing-in-bash). However, I'm not sure why the solution works.

Should I add the information about the solution to my question and request an explanation? Or should I go ahead and post the inexplicable solution as an answer and start a new question querying why it works?

Comment: that uh, "PLEASE READ FIRST" of your question is ruining the preview that users get when they see your question in the question list.

Comment: @KevinB Unfortunate, but necessary I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't think it is, those comments can be flagged as no longer needed.

Comment: It's there to prevent even more such comments. And seems to be working. But if it really needs to be moved/removed I can. I suppose it's probably not great for SEO either.

Comment: Add it as an answer to your question to close it out and for the benefit of folks who share the issue. And explain in the answer that you don't understand why it works and ask for clarification or additional answers that go into more detail. If someone does answer you can reward them for clarifying for you.